# Memcached for each website on the server

Tags: php, memcached

I want cache values by keys for each website.

For example:

If I set `$memcached->set('somekey', 'somevalue')` on website A and call `$memcached->get('somekey')` on website B, I got `'somevalue'`.

How to stop it?

Comment: As I answered on the other, duplicate question, the only solution would be to run two Memcached daemons on their own ports/UNIX sockets and let each site connect to a different one.

Answer (score 0):

There is no native way to do this within either the [memcache](http://php.net/book.memcache) or the [memcached](http://php.net/book.memcached) interfaces.

You must manually alter the key to be unique per-site.  You can do this by prefixing the key.  For example,

```
$memcached->set($site_name . 'somekey', 'somevalue');
```

and

```
$memcached->get($site_name . 'somekey');
```

where you have defined `$site_name` in your code in a unique way per-site.

You may wish to create a class that extends `Memcache` or `Memcached` (depending on which extension you're using) that overrides the various getters and setters to *automatically* add the site-specific prefix.

Comment: Thank you but everybody can type same key like the unique. For example if I type $memcached->set($site_name . 'somekey', 'somevalue'); in website A, in website B I can type $memcached->set('site A name'. 'somekey', 'someanothervalue'); and change website A cache.. so this not good way. There is another way maybe? Thank you very much!